# Calculating Prices

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate the final price for "ordering a product" off a website and I am just wondering where I am going wrong as either shows an alert with "€NaN[HTML element]"

However right now it is saying there is an error at $('.smallPrice') 
I am wondering is there a way to inherit from the selection input types..

Edit - Now printing "€NaN

```js
function multiply(){
 
 var smallPrice  = 149.99;
 var mediumPrice = 249.99;
 var largePrice = 399.99;

 var quantity = document.getElementById($("#quantity").value);

 var stanDeliver = 20.00;
 var expresDeliver = 33.00;
 var nextDeliver = 50.00;


 if ($("#smallPrice").val() == smallPrice){
  var total = quantity * smallPrice;
 }else if ($("#mediumPrice").val() == mediumPrice){
  var total = quantity * mediumPrice;
 }else{
  var total = quantity * largePrice;
 }

 var deli = document.getElementById($("#deliver").value);
 var total = quantity * pricing + deli;
 console.log(total,size)
 alert("The price is €"+total);
 }
```

```html
<table id="pricing">
  <tr>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Delivery</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" name="Quantity" min="1" max="2" 
            id="quantity">
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="coloured">
      <option value="rose">Rose Gold</option>
      <option value="space">Space</option>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="size" id="size">
      <option value="small" id="smallPrice">3.0mm</option>
      <option value="medium" id="mediumPrice">4.5mm</option>
      <option value="large" id="largePrice">6.0mm</option>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="deliver" id="deliver">
      <option value="standard" id="stanDeliver">Standard EU Delivery</option>
      <option value="express" id="expresDeliver">Express 3 Day Delivery </option>
      <option value="nextday" id="nextDeliver">Next Day Delivery</option>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="total" value="€" size="5"  id="total" readonly  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="price" value=euro></tr>
  <input type = "submit" size = "20" name = "Send" id = "submit" value = "Send" onClick = "multiply()">

</table>
```

Comment: I think it is because $(".smallPrice") returns a jQuery html element instead of the value of the select that you are looking for.

Comment: @Bosen would that mean it could possibly work if I imported jQuery?

Comment: i didn' see `.smallPrice`  and  `mediumPrice` element

Comment: Also, if u are looking to get the id of smallPrice, i think u shld use "#smallPrice" instead of ".smallPrice" as the latter is referring to classes

Comment: U can try $("#smallPrice").val() to get the value. You shld import jQuery as well for it to work

Comment: It works however it does not print a price it prints ``€NaN[object HTMLSelectElement]

Comment: There are multiple issues with the code you have shared. The `select` tags are not closed. The  line `var deli = document.getElementById("deliver")` should be `$("#deliver").value`. I am assuming you want to pick the value selected in the drop down. Then you are adding the price to the value selected but since that is a string you will either get a concatenated string or NaN

Comment: @MohitMutha Yes you are correct. I will make these changes now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're treating jQuery objects as values.

The `$` function takes in a selector as a parameter and returns any matching elements. For example, `$('.smallPrice')` searches for all elements with the style class `smallPrice`. If you wanted to search for the element with the id `smallPrice`, you could prefix the id with a hash: `$('#smallPrice')`.

This code doesn't really need jQuery as you can use native javascript to get the elements by id:

```
var prices = {
  small: 149.99,
  medium: 249.99,
  large: 399.99,
  standard: 20.00,
  express: 33.00,
  nextday: 50.00
};

function multiply(){
  var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
  var size = document.getElementById("size").value;
  var deli = document.getElementById("deliver").value;

  if(!quantity){
    return alert("Please enter a quantity");
  }

  var total = (quantity * prices[size]) + prices[deli];

  console.log(total)
  alert("The price is €"+total);
}
```

Here is a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/jM3sYAbfKJ31joot1fUX?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out the flaws, I just have been looking at it for so long that it doesn't look out of place.

Comment: @KyleMcCann No problem - sometimes all you need is a 2nd pair of eyes!

Comment: @ Michael Kucinski Very True well at least that is sorted now :)

Answer (score 0):

You got just a few errors on your JS code, and some HTML tags were not closed:

```
        <!-- HTML -->
<table id="pricing">
    <tr>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Delivery</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="Quantity" min="1" max="2" 
        id="quantity">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="coloured">
              <option value="rose">Rose Gold</option>
              <option value="space">Space</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="size" id="size">
              <option value="small">3.0mm</option>
              <option value="medium">4.5mm</option>
              <option value="large">6.0mm</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="deliver" id="deliver">
            <option value="standard" id="stanDeliver">Standard EU Delivery</option>
            <option value="express" id="expresDeliver">Express 3 Day Delivery </option>
            <option value="nextday" id="nextDeliver">Next Day Delivery</option>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="total" value="€" size="5"  id="total" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="price" value=euro></tr>
    <input type = "submit" size = "20" name = "Send" id = "submit" value = "Send" onClick = "multiply()">
</table>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function multiply(){

        var smallPrice  = 149.99;
        var mediumPrice = 249.99;
        var largePrice = 399.99;

        // Set delivery prices on an object to compare against the value selected for delivery
        var deliveryPrices = {
            'standard' : 10.00,
            'express' : 20.50,
            'nextday' : 40.00
        };

        // Gets the quantity value as a number
        var quantity = Number($("#quantity").val());

        // Compare the prices, i do not understand your logic here
        if ( $('#smallPrice').val() == smallPrice){
            var total = quantity * smallPrice;
        } else if ($("#mediumPrice").val() == mediumPrice){
            var total = quantity * mediumPrice;
        } else {
            var total = quantity * largePrice;
        }

        // Get the delivery value
        var deli = $("#deliver").val();

        // Adds the delivery cost (set previously) to the total
        var total = total + deliveryPrices[deli];

       alert("The price is €"+total);

    }

</script>
```